# access-2013 report opens very slow

Tags: performance, ms-access, odbc, report

I've a weird problem here with a report which I use every day.
I've moved from XP to WIN-7 some time ago and use access 2013.
(Language is german, so sorry I can only guess how the modes are called in english)

"Suddenly" (I really can't say when this started) opening the report in "report-view" takes VERY long. Around 1 minute, or so. Then, switching to "page-view" and formatting the report takes only 2 or 3 seconds. Switching back to report-view, again takes 1 minute.

The report has a complex Query as datasource. (In fact, a UNION of 8 sub-queries) Opening the this query displays the data after 1 second which is ok.

All tables are "linked" from the same ODBC Datasource, which points to a mysql server on our network.

Further testing I opened every table the queries use, one after another. I noticed that opening these tables takes around 9 seconds for every single table. It doesn't matter if it's a small or big table. Always these 9 seconds.

The ODBC datasource is defined using the IP address of the server, not the name. So I consider it not being a nameserver problem / timeout/ ...

What could cause this slowdown on opening tables ????
I'm puzzeled..

Comment: Reboot the machine with SQL Server? If you look at the tables directly in Sql Server management studio, do you also get this 9 seconds delay?

Comment: Hi erg! The server runs for more than 1 year now without reboot. Any other client get's a sql-response from this server within msec... It's definitely a problem somewhere at win-7 or access.

Comment: A windows server without any maintance reboot within 1 year,  I'm impressed ;) How did you manage to apply security updates without rebooting the machine? :P Anyway: The other clients access the same database/tables and do not have the problem? From within server management studio the problem also does not appear (accessing exactly the same tables)? You could also try to enable logging inside sql server to see if you get any hints from there whats eating the time..

Comment: 1) Did you try taking a fresh copy of the Access app running on one of those "fast clients" ? 2) try comparing performance with the same default printer

Comment: Hi erg! You got me wrong there. I **never** said the server is a windows-server! It's a linux machine runnig **my**sql, not mssql. And Yes, all other clients do not have this problem. Only ACCESS has ist. I really can't imagine what access is "waiting for" during this 9 seconds.

Comment: Interesting: I did monitor the network. After opening this report, Access sends a lot of sql queries to the server and gets a lot of responses from the server. This all happens within the first second. And then, for the rest of 2 minutes, ther is **NO** network traffic at all. It seems that access is only concerned with itself using 100% of 1 core.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few steps I would try:

1. Taking a fresh copy of the Access app running on one of those "fast clients" and see if that solves the issue
2. try comparing performance with a fast client after setting the **same default printer**
3. check the version of the driver on both machines, and if you rely on a DSN, compare them